# Run JSP on Java Play

Tags: java, jsp, playframework

I have just started using the `Java Play framework`, and I have a few questions...

I've developed a web application, which was managed using `Maven 3.0`, hosted on `Tomcat 7.0`, and containing a whole bunch of `JSP` files. 
Our team recently decided to run everything using the Play framework, and I'm just wonder if there is a fast way to import my original project into Play? also, how does play recognise JSP files? where to put them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, play framework view template uses groovy (1.x) or scala (2.x) to render the data. Therefore, there is no way to use or replace the old jsp files in your new system. You have to convert the old bulk jsp files into the new views